# Unicode strings in JSON string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, unicode, console

I know how to consume JSON string in Objective C.

For example:

```
{
  "name":"school",
  "address":"very near here"
}
```

This is easy because the strings are plain English.

The situation is I'd like to read JSON data that contains Unicode strings

For example:

```
{
  "name":"trường học",  
  "address":"rất gần đây"  
}
```

The strings above are Vietnamese.

or

```
{  
  "name":" 名 学校",    
  "address":"近义词"    
}
```

The strings above are Chinese.

But when I display these strings in Xcode console or in UITextView, I see garbage characters.

Do you know how to read and display Unicode JSON string in iPhone projects?

Comment: How do you read the JSON? From a file or network? How do you parse it?

Comment: I read JSON from a network with ASIHTTPRequest class and use JSON library to parse the data, everything works fine with standard English, but with Unicode data (foreign languages) I see garbage when displaying them to either console or UI components (UILable, UITextView)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people have been suggesting before me, the underlying is most likely below the actual JSON parsing and display. Maybe your webserver is not setting the encoding correctly? Assuming the file on the server is utf8-encoded, you can force it with ASIHTTPRequest like:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString]]; 
[request setResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

If this doesn't help, you might want to post the http headers (produce them with wget or curl) and the actual http client code. 
You might also want to check out [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) which provides a turn-key solution to http-client and json parsing.

Comment: Thanks cellcortex, I use | httpRequest.defaultResponseEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding; | and now I can see unicode text in the console.

Comment: Hi guys, I have exactly the same issue and tried setting encoding to NSUTF8StringEncoding and server also using the same but I see same garbage characters! Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

An NSString is essentially UTF16 representation.  If you're reading from the network or a file the representation is likely either UTF8 or some national code page.  Most likely your problem is in the conversion from network/file representation into the NSString fed into the JSON parser, not in the JSON parser itself.

Comment: Exactly! I think I have this issue. Server uses UTF8 and I set ASIHTTPRequest response encoding to NSUTF8StringEncoding as mentioned above but still when I print response string(before parsing it using SBJSON library), it prints garbage characters! Not sure what the issue is. Could you help?

Comment: You need to examine the "garbage" (probably in hex) and figure out what's getting mucked up.

Comment: It's coming something strange characters and not sure what should I do to debug it. I have posted my question here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316813/ios-handling-http-requests-unicode-characters Could you please help there. Thanks.

Comment: If I use Google Chrome's Simple Rest Client to see server's returned JSON string. It displays perfect characters.

Comment: It has been fixed now. I was setting NSUTF8StringEncoding  to responseEncoding rather than defaultResponseEncoding!!

Answer (score 0):

The JSON spec mandates that JSON data be encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32.

- Verify that other Unicode strings print out correctly to the console.
- Verify that your JSON data is encoded in UTF-8.
- If both of these are true, something is wrong with the JSON parser library you are using.