# "Invalid escape sequence found in "" string." reported from JSON call using RestKit

Tags: ios, restkit, jsonkit

The web service call is failing with the message **"Invalid escape sequence found in "" string."** being shown through `objectLoader:didFailWithError:` method.

The JSON that is being fetched from the server has some \ characters and that appears to be the reason for this failure.

How can this be avoided. A quick search says that `JKSerializeOptionEscapeForwardSlashes` should be sepcifed in `JSONKit`, but how to implement this with RestKit.

Comment: What library are you using to do the JSON parsing?

Comment: There is nothing that I am adding separately, RESTKit uses JSONKit. So it is JSONKit.

Comment: The data I am getting in JSON is in Chinese. The JSON payload has a node as 天坛显 微神经 外科 \351\253\230 级培训班. Yet when I locate the same node in a JSON viewer, it is appearing as 天坛显微神经外科é«级培训班. Why are some of these characters getting 'escaped' along with some numbers?

Comment: On a closer look, these characters are causing trouble. é  «

Comment: I see two possible errors: 1) I don't think JSON supports the Chinese character set, it's UTF8, and 2) if "\" is an escape sequence, there is an escape for a number of 300+. I haven't had much experience with JSON, so maybe wait for someone else's comments. But have you tried running the website through one of the online validators?

Comment: Also, post the JSON URL and we can have a look at it for you

Comment: Ok appears I may be wrong about Chinese character support. Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718589/unicode-strings-in-json-string

Comment: Turned out the JSON was invalid due to the special characters. However, don't understand that how come then that it was formatter properly by http://jsonviewer.stack.hu

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you started your url with "http://" or not?